# Confusion Matrix in R for Bayes Network

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, confusion-matrix

How can I build a confusion matrix in R for the Bayesian Network?

There are a lot of library's for the Naive Bayes, but are there are also library's for the confusion matrix, or does somebody have a example of bayesian confusion matrix for the Bayesian Network?

Comment: R package `caret`.

Comment: @rbm which command should I use in the caret package? because i don't see the bayesian network listed there

Comment: If you are using naive Bayes modelling, all you need to do is generate the observed and predicted values. You can then pass these to some custom function(ie caret (or better, calculate the statistics yourself).

Comment: I know how i can make a confusing matrix for the naive bayes(where we assume there are no dependencies).. I want to know how i can create a confusing matrix for the bayesian network(where we assume there is dependencies).